# jquery scrollTop doesn't work (always returns 0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I want to do 2 things -- change section of page on scroll (on scroll down next section appears, on scroll up previous) like [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jtpbq9zf/), and fade in menu when `scroll down > 100px`. The problem is that in both situations, I should use the `scrollTop()` method, which always returns `0`. For example, when I try to fade in the menu background:

```
$(function() {
$('body').on('scroll', function () {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      $('.hidden-white-bg').fadeIn();
    }else{
      $('.hidden-white-bg').fadeOut();
    }
});
});
```

When I try to scroll down, the menu doesn't appear. Here's my main markup:

```
<div id="landing-wrapper" class="full-screen-element">
     <section id="main-sectcion" class="full-screen-element">....</section>
     <section id="all-possible" class="full-screen-element">....</section>
     <section id="location" class="full-screen-element">....</section>
     <section id="everything-provide" class="full-screen-element">....</section>
     <section id="main-slider" class="full-screen-element">....</section>
</div>
```

I have the same code as in that jsFiddle, but when I try to scroll nothing happens (scroll doesn't work at all!) and no error in console.

I guess styles causes this problem (not sure, but anyway). I added the `full-screen-element` class to each element to make them 100% height:

```
.full-screen-element{
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto !important;
}
```

I also tried to use [jQuery Mouse Wheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel) but same problem there.

Comment: I dont see .hidden-white-bg class in your js fiddle

Comment: You are overwriting the height with your height: auto !important; which shortens the height from 528px to 100%

Comment: thanks for reply. `.hidden-white-bg` is in the question, not in fiddle, as I said I need to do 2 things. on of them is on scroll show prev/next section and also show menu when `scroll down > 100px`

Comment: Use this
$(document).ready(function(){
//Your Code
});

Comment: i tried to remove `full-screen-element` class at all, but nothings changed

Comment: i also tried `$(document).ready(function()` but didn't help

Comment: `$('body').on('scroll' ...` does not seem to work, but works on document or window. `$('body').scroll(function(){...})` should work.

Comment: @Aman OP was already using `$(function() {`which is the short, and since v3 recommended, syntax for [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: tried this `$('body').scroll(function()` also tried with `window` and `'html'` but same problem

Comment: Is it a wordpress site? Are you getting any errors in your console.

Comment: It applies to window objects, but also to scrollable frames and elements with the overflow CSS property set to scroll (or auto when the element's explicit height or width is less than the height or width of its contents). In that case i think you need to set some height to your element.

Comment: its not wordpress, server side is on laravel

Comment: you mean set height to `section`' elemenet? I set it to `100%`

Comment: On what browser are you testing? I found that the fiddle doesn't work in IE11 but works fine in Chrome

Comment: i tested in firefox and chrome and fiddle there works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally found out, the problem was because `body` element has `overflow: hidden`, set it to `visible` and it works